# How to use Baxter in simulation with Rviz and moveit?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have come across the following tutorials of Baxter.

[Baxter Simulator](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation)

[Baxter with Moveit](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial)

However, what I need is a tutorial that will enable me to work with Baxter in simulation as we can do with PR2 in Rviz. I need a launch file that will launch the Baxter Robot in Rviz. We have that for PR2 in [this](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html).

[This](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation) Baxter simulator tutorial is with Gazebo, I want to perform the same tasks in Baxter with Rviz that I did with PR2.

Could anyone share a launch file and an example python code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325925/how-to-use-baxter-in-simulation-with-rviz-and-moveit?/) by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2019-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial you are looking for is [this one for using Baxter with MoveIt](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial). Follow the simulation tutorial to get Baxter going in Gazebo, then follow the above tutorial, starting from where it says "In another RSDK terminal session, Launch the rviz MoveIt! plugin".

In general, any MoveIt-enabled robot will have a package called something like `baxter_moveit_config`. This package will contain launch files for starting the MoveIt interfaces, the rviz-based GUI tool, etc.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-17**:
You also need to put the baxter_moveit_config [package](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_robots/tree/indigo-devel/baxter/baxter_moveit_config) in your src folder

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-18**:
@Geoff I am having another issue, the planner is neither working in Rviz if I just drag the interactive marker and then plan nor if I run [this](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) tutorial. It keeps failing when I drag the marker in Rviz and then plan and when I run the tutorial code, it keeps saying no motion plan found.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-06-18**:
Please ask a new question for that.

**Comment by [Tawfiq Chowdhury](https://answers.ros.org/users/39656/tawfiq-chowdhury/) on 2019-06-21**:
You also need to run these two commands in two separate terminals from [this](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/MoveIt_Tutorial)

```
rosrun baxter_tools enable_robot.py -e
rosrun baxter_interface joint_trajectory_action_server.py
```